# Genymotion is not working and freeze

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I had genymotion for couple of years and it was working fine with no issues

Today genymotion is not working fine and freeze its window

Also when I run the emulator the right menu for genymotion emualtor are in white and I can't even minimize it or click the exit button

I have tried to uninstall genymotino and virtual machine also tried to add new different emulators and i'm still having the same problem.

Can someone help me to fix this problem I had genymotion for a long time and it's the best and fastest emulator I have ever used.

[image: emulator is no working and freez like this and right menu are in white]

Comment: what else has changed between "working fine" and "Today"

Comment: @Henry I only deleted the registry for generation  , but I have installed it again and still not working